# What are ways to destroy a country's government/monarchy by using the underground/black market/illegal doings?

Tags: society, economy, medieval, royalty

I'm creating a story in which the main characters want nothing more than the complete and absolute downfall of an entire country, starting from the top and its royalty all the way to the corruption of the people. One character has complete holding over the dark 'underground,' and oversees everything varying from the establishment of drug rings to the distribution of child-slaves. What are ways they can continue unraveling the strings of the monarchy by using the underground as their method? I have several ideas, but am interested if there's anything unique or new that could throw the story in a new direction!

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Worldbuilding Juniper. I understand your enthusiasm however stackexchange is better suited towards a single question answer type response.  This isn't a forum for discussion and the potential methods that a underground world could overthrow a monarchy has been the subject of many movies, books and games. You could fill an entire library with possible ways this would work. If instead, you want to compare methods or ask for flaws in the methods you have thought of, that would be more on topic and much likelier to not be closed as too broad or opinion based.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  You're asking what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions), which isn't a good fit for our site.  Please review these links and help us by improving your question.

Comment: There seem to be some serious misunderstandings here about how monarchies work, how corruption generally functions, and about how quite a few monarchies across centuries were *strengthened* by criminality. Including a couple in the current era.

Comment: Get control of the media

Comment: Research the Koch Brothers.